# Decrease product quantity in database after order is placed with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, cart

I have cart on the site and so far everything work perfectly. Now I'm trying to make quantity for each product which admin can add in backend ( already done ) and when customer order product(s) to decrease quantity in database.

So far as I said admin panel is ready and can add quantity to product which is saved in database. Here is my cart submit controller

```
public function orderSubmit() {
    $cart = Session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
    if (count($cart) < 1) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    $validatorRules = array(
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha'      
    );

    Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/cart/order?_token=' . csrf_token())->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $order = new Order();
    $order->user_id = self::$user->user_id;
    $order->data = json_encode($cart, true);
    $order->info = Input::get('additional_info');

    $order->save();
    Session::put(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());

    return Redirect::to('/)->with('message_success', 'Order created! We will contact you shortly to confirm your order details.');
}
```

The cart is saved in `$order->data = json_encode($cart, true);` and in database information for product(s) etc look

```
{"title":"Test Product","description":"You save 25%","quantity":1,"price":135}
```

If there are multiple products in order above array will have also them.

What I can't understand is how to extract which product is ordered and how many pieces from it so I can later update database quantity field for each product?

I don't even know from where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$cart` is an array and based on the json you provided, you'll need to:

1. Add the product id to the `$cart` otherwise it will be pretty much impossible to know what are the products for that order
2. With the product id for each product on the `$cart`, you can now loop the cart products and update them. Something like the following code.

   ```
   public function orderSubmit() {
       $cart = Session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
       if (count($cart) < 1) {
           return Redirect::to('/');
       }

       $validatorRules = array(
           'captcha' => 'required|captcha'      
       );

       Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
       $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validatorRules);

       if ($validator->fails()) {
           return Redirect::to('/cart/order?_token=' . csrf_token())->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
       }
       \DB::beginTransaction();

       try {
           $order = new Order();
           $order->user_id = self::$user->user_id;
           $order->data = json_encode($cart, true);
           $order->info = Input::get('additional_info');

           $order->save();

           foreach ($cart as $item) {
               $product = Product::find($item->id);
               $product->decrement('votes', $item->quantity);
           }

           Session::put(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());

           \DB::commit();

           return Redirect::to('/')->with('message_success', 'Order created! We will contact you shortly to confirm your order details.');
       } catch (\Exception $ex) {
           \DB::rollback();

           return Redirect::to('/cart/order?_token=' . csrf_token())->withErrors($ex->getMessage())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
       }
   }
   ```

I added the code for the transaction to assure the quantity is decreased when the order is stored correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For those using *resource controller* or a *simpler/easy* answer:

```php
public function create()
{
    $stocks = Stock::all();
    //dd($stocks);
    return view('sales.create', compact('stocks'));
    //$sales = Sale::pluck('stock_id')->prepend('stock_id');
    //$sales = DB::table('stocks')->select('stock_id')->get();
    //return view('sales.create')->with('sales',$sales);
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'stock_id' => 'required',
        'product_name' => 'required',
        'sale_quantity' => 'required',
        'unit_selling_price' => 'required',
        'total_sales_cost' => 'required'
        ]);

    //create stock
    $sale = new Sale;
    $sale->stock_id = $request->input('stock_id');
    $sale->product_name = $request->input('product_name');
    $sale->sale_quantity = $request->input('sale_quantity');
    $sale->unit_selling_price = $request->input('unit_selling_price');
    $sale->total_sales_cost = $request->input('total_sales_cost');
    $sale->stock_quantity =
        $sale->save();
    DB::table('stocks')->where('stock_name', $request->input('product_name'))->decrement('stock_quantity', $request->input('sale_quantity'));

    return redirect('/sales')->with('success', 'Sale Saved');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and working perfectly.

```
$check_stock = Product::where('id', $product->product_id)->first()->stock_quantity;

      if ($check_stock > 0 && $check_stock >= $product->quantity) {
        $stock = Product::where('id', $product->product_id)->decrement('stock_quantity', $product->quantity);
      }else{
        watchOut('warning', 'Opps', 'Stock shortage');
        return back();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

decrease array product quantity in database after order is placed with laravel

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Session;
    use App\Models\prod;
    use App\Models\addinv;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    class ocsController extends Controller
    {
        public function ocs() {
             $products = prod::all();
             return view('ocs',compact('products'));
        }
    
    
        public function assposxd(Request $request){
        $unique_no = addinv::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->pluck('id')->first();
            if($unique_no == null or $unique_no == ""){
            #If Table is Empty
            $unique_no = 1;
            }
            else{
            #If Table has Already some Data
            $unique_no = $unique_no + 1;
          }
    
           $product_name = $request->product_name;
           $cost_name = $request->cost_name;
           $qty = $request->qty;
           $price = $request->price;
           $preTotal = $request->preTotal;
           $subTotal = $request->subTotal;
           $total_qty = $request->total_qty;
           $taxAmount = $request->taxAmount;
           $total = $request->total;
           $dis = $request->dis;
           $final_total = $request->final_total;
    
         
          for($i=1; $i < count($product_name);$i++){
    
             $datasave = [
              'arry_no' => $i,
              'entry_code'       => 'A00'.$unique_no,
              'product_name'     => $product_name[$i],
              'qty'              => $qty[$i],
              'price'            => $price[$i],
              'preTotal'         => $preTotal[$i],
              'subTotal'         => $subTotal,
              'total_qty'        => $total_qty,
              'taxAmount'        => $taxAmount,
              'total'            => $total,
              'dis'              => $dis,
              'final_total'      => $final_total,
              'cost_name'        => $cost_name
            ];
    
    
    
    
            $staff = new addinv();
            $staff->insert($datasave);
    
           
           ]);
    //         $productDetails = DB::table('prod')->where([$datasave => $product_name])->get();
    //         foreach( $productDetails as $pro) {
    //     addinv::where('id',  $pro->id )->decrement('prod', $pro->qty);
    // }
    
    // Prod::whereIn('id', $datasave)->decrement(['qty' => 1]);
    
            // $product = Prod::find($id, $qty = ['qty']);
    
            //               $stock = Prod::where('id', $product->id);
            //                $stock->decrement('qty', 1);
    
                          //   $product = Prod::find(1);
    
                          // $stock = Prod::where('id', $product->id);
                          //  $stock->decrement('qty', 1);
    
                          //   $product = Prod::find(3);
    
                          // $stock = Prod::where('id', $product->id);
                          //  $stock->decrement('qty', 1);
            // $stock->decrement('qty', $datasave['qty']);
    
            //  $product = prod::find($id);
    
            // foreach( $product as $pro) {
    
            // $id = $pro->id
            // $qty = $pro->qty
            // }
             // $product = prod::find(1);
    
             //  $stock = prod::where('id', $product->id)->toArray();
             //       $stock->decrement('qty', 1);
          }
         
         
    
          $invc="A00$unique_no";
         
          $request->session()->put('current_code','ab');
         return redirect('/invoice/'.$invc);
          
    
    
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: decrease array product quantity in database after order is placed with laravel