# Reduce stock number in laravel

Tags: laravel

**How can I reduce the number of stock in laravel?**

In my products table i have stock column where i set numbers of item i have and i want to reduce it in 2 conditions:

1- when is added to order table (not when the product is in user cart)

2- when the order status is not cancelled (if order status become cancelled stocks increase back)

> PS: currently I have no code for this matter that's why i didn't share
>   any code, **I'm seeking for idea of how done it**. Base on that i will
>   make functions and share here to complete it.

JSON of Order

```
"[{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\‌​":1,\"attributes\":[‌​{\"attr\":{\"label\"‌​:\"Gray\",\"price\":‌​\"7000.00\"}}],\"con‌​ditions\":[]},{\"id\‌​":27,\"name\":\"new product\",\"price\":7246,\"quantity\":2,\"attributes\":[],\"‌​conditions\":[]}]"
```

## UPDATE

base on @btl answer I added code below in my `order` model:

```
protected static function boot()
  {
      parent::boot();


      $productIdsAndQuantities = $this->products->map(function ($product) {
        return [$product->id => $product->quantity];
      });

      static::updating(function (Order $order) {
          // restock if cancelled
          $oldStatus = OrderStatus::find($order->getOriginal('orderstatus_id'));
          if ($oldStatus->title !== 'Cancelled' && $order->orderstatus->title === 'Cancelled') {
               $order->products->each(function(Product $product) {
                    $stock = $product->getAttribute('stock');
                    $product->update([
                      'stock' => $stock + $product->order->getAttribute($productIdsAndQuantities)
                    ]);
               });
          }
      });
  }
```

I think this code needs fix in `$productIdsAndQuantities` and `$product->update(['stock' => $stock + $product->order->getAttribute($productIdsAndQuantities)]);` parts before i can use it.

currently i get error below when i try to add my cart detail to orders table

> Using $this when not in object context

## UPDATE 2

I changed my code to:

```
protected static function boot()
  {
      parent::boot();



      static::updating(function (Order $order) {
        $productIdsAndQuantities = $order->product_name->map(function ($product) {
          return [$product->id => $product->quantity];
        });
          // restock if cancelled
          $oldStatus = OrderStatus::find($order->getOriginal('orderstatus_id'));
          if ($oldStatus->title !== 'Cancelled' && $order->orderstatus->title === 'Cancelled') {
               $order->products->each(function(Product $product) {
                    $stock = $product->getAttribute('stock');
                    $product->update([
                      'stock' => $stock + $product->order->getAttribute($productIdsAndQuantities)
                    ]);
               });
          }
      });
  }
```

now my order will be placed but nothing changes on stock column.

any idea?

Comment: You should create another table name stock with associated order_id and product_id then just add details of stock rise or fall.

Comment: @SagarGautam then what about my stock column in products table?

Comment: Does stock column have initial value ?

Comment: @SagarGautam no is input.

Comment: Add an event listener for `Order::saving`.

Comment: @fubar could you be more specific?

Comment: So it's value is taken from input while adding product and value falls or rise in above two events. Am I right ?

Comment: Create an event listener. When an order is created, decrement the stock. When the order status changes to cancelled, increment the stock. When the order is deleted, increment the stock.

Comment: @SagarGautam correct.

Comment: @fubar interesting idea, do you have any sample or link that i can read how to do it?

Comment: Since just incrementing/decrementing value of stock might cause problem later and you have to track the overall change of the stock value column, I think you need another table.

Comment: I agree with @SagarGautam that another table gives more traceability. And here's a link to read about model events - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events.

Comment: @fubar Exactly,

Comment: @SagarGautam before i decide to create 3rd table, would you mind tell me how then i can print stocks in front-end to tell users that this product no more available? another thought: what will happen when in 3rd table related stock sum become more that product column value?

Comment: In my opinion, don't change any thing in product table, place value of stock column while creating product, when ever the event you have stated above occur add new column which defines rise or fall associated with product and order. You can show product unavailable while stock column value becomes zero. I hope you understand.

Comment: @SagarGautam this is what i get from you see i'm correct: 1-create new table `stocks` with columns of `product_id` `order_id` `stock (which is quantity in order)` and then i do such thing in my front-end to reduce stocks `$product->stock - $stocks->stock = new value` right?!

Comment: Not exactly, but similar. You have value of stock at product table. Add +1 or -1 on stock column of stocks table and increment or decrement the stock column value in product table at the same time. When stock value at product table becomes zero then product becomes unavailable.

Comment: @SagarGautam well i'm a bit confused now, would you mind post a sample as an answer or share some codes in gist/wherever? you blind my mind now LOL can't get any picture of your solution in my mind. ckckck

Comment: This is because you have not started to code LOL, I will try to add some code.

Comment: I've added my way of thinking to this problem as answer below, take a moment to see it.

Comment: #SOLVED The answer of my question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593304/decrease-product-quantity-in-database-after-order-is-placed-with-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

the trick was to use `try {` on my `CartController` when I wanted to save my data in `orders` table there I should place my codes like:

```
try {
        $order = new Order();
        $qty = Cart::getTotalQuantity();
        $order->product_data = $cartItems;
        $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       // rest of it...
        Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
        //trick is in this part
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $product = Product::find($item->id);
            $product->decrement('stock', $item->quantity);
        }
```

the answer was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593304/decrease-product-quantity-in-database-after-order-is-placed-with-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Your tables look like,

**Product**

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');

        ......

        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

**Stock**

```
    Schema::create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->enum('fall_rise',[-1,1]);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
    });
```

**orders**

```
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        .....

        .....

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now, add a sample product with stock value 10 like

```
 $product = new Product();
 $product->name = "abc";

 ......

 $product->stock = 10;
 $product->save();
```

Now, when abc is ordered, add details in order table. Now, stock value to be decreased then update value of stock column in product by 10-1 = 9, add record in stocks table like

Sample values,

```
 product_id = 1;
 order_id = 1;

 ....

 fall_rise = -1;
```

In this way, when 10 stocks of the product are ordered then stock column becomes  zero and hence product becomes unavailable. If you want to fetch only available products then use query like,

```
$available_products = Product::where('stock', '>', 0)->get();
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: @mafortis okay I hope it'll help

Comment: 1 question before i run migrate command? you've mentioned `$table->enum('fall_rise',[-1,1]);` in schema what if user order more than 1 item of some products? still reduce 1 from stocks?

Comment: I've thought purchase of one stock, you can make integer column `fall_rise`  so that you can make any stock value change.

Answer (score 0):

Register model events to handle updates on orders.

In your Order model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function (Order $order) {
        // restock if cancelled
        $oldStatus = OrderStatus::find($order->getOriginal('orderstatus_id');
        if ($oldStatus->name !== 'cancelled' && $order->orderstatus->name === 'cancelled') {
             $order->products->each(function(Product $product) {
                  $stock = $product->getAttribute('stock');
                  $product->update(['stock' => $stock + $product->order->getAttribute('quantity_of_product_ordered')]);
             });
        }

        // added to order table similar to above...
        // check if it's a new product id being added to the order, decrease stock quantity accordingly...
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: so in your way i don't need 3rd table as @SagarGautam suggested?

Comment: another thing `(that's my bad i didn't mention in question)` my order statuses are dynamically i get them by `id` in column named `orderstatus_id` should i change anything in your code?

Comment: I don't see a `stocks` table being necessary unless you are tracking product movements and need a historical record of it. Your order status would just add another query to look up the correct status id in this case. It wouldn't be a straight `===` comparison to the string like I have now.

Comment: I updated my answer but guessed at some attribute and relation names, you should change them accordingly.

Comment: ok this was for order model, should i add it in product model too? and where this come from? `quantity_of_product_ordered`

Comment: It should be enough only having it on the Order model, otherwise you'll be changing the stock levels more than onc. `quantity_of_product_ordered` would be the quantity of a particular product for the given order. I just made that name up for demo purposes. So if an order had 10 of product A and 20 of product B, `quantity_of_product_ordered` would be the value you modified your stock level by, 10 and 20 respectively.

Comment: i get it now, but i'm facing nightmare with  my orders table (not sure if u were involved my past days questions) but i asked like 10 question to get my order data out of it :-D, the thing is my orders saves as json (SAMPLE `"[{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Gray\",\"price\":\"7000.00\"}}],\"conditions\":[]},{\"id\":27,\"name\":\"new product\",\"price\":7246,\"quantity\":2,\"attributes\":[],\"conditions\":[]}]"`) as you see i have 2 product in this order `id29` and `id27` how should i get their quantity?

Comment: Why are you storing it like that? Is this a legacy application or can you change that to not save as a JSON string and use a dedicated table?

Comment: i cannot change it maximun i can save as array instead of json (almost same!) my cart is coming from package and package cart session will be stored in orders table as order

Comment: Post a link to the Cart package you are using please.

Comment: This section tells you exactly how to get the collection of items from the cart and how to get each item's quantity, id, attributes, price, etc. https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#items. I really don't think you should be using that JSON string at all. Furthermote, the data is being serialized/unserialized through the model so you would need to unserialize the string the json decode it.

Comment: yes as long as it is in session (cart) not when i saved it in table such as `orders` there `getcontent()` will not work.

Comment: This shows you how to reload a cart from a database: https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#storage. I would use this specifically for your situation.

Comment: Here is a discussion with your exact situation, answered by the developer of the cart himself: https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/issues/110

Comment: that's my discussion before get my orders table to work :) as u see i used to use serialized and that brought me many issues so i decided to use json  and then they suggested me to use loop for my json codes which result is code that you see

Comment: now what i think (might be wrong) is to loop orders individually (which it is because we are in order model) and get order items quantity to replace with `quantity_of_product_ordered` i think we need a loop in your boot.

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I think that would probably work. Seems completely reasonable to me.

Comment: if i add such loop is that correct?  `$qty = 0;
      foreach($this->product_name as $ddf) {
      $qty = $ddf['quantity'];
      }
      return $qty;` would that get quantities?

Comment: Well it's hard to say exactly since you have no code, but the idea is there. I would use relations and collection methods, personally like: `$productIdsAndQuantities = $order->products->map(function ($product) { return [$product->id => $product->quantity]; });`.

Comment: my code is your answer :) all i have is what wrote here, note: column in my orders table that hold json code named `product_name`

Comment: when i add your loop to boot function it gives error for `$order` so i changed it to `$this` and still gives error of `Using $this when not in object context` here is your code i changed: `$productIdsAndQuantities = $this->products->map(function ($product) {
        return [$product->id => $product->quantity];
      });`

Comment: the boot method is static, you cannot use `$this` in static methods.

Comment: what should i do?